# retrieve filename and use it as class selector with LESS

Tags: less

Is it possible to retrieve the name of a file and use it as class selector?
I have a file called "colorScheme.less" and inside of this file I have alle the style rules prefixed with '.colorScheme". 
How is it possible to replace this selector, when i change the filename of colorScheme.less ?

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

There may be a way to use the javascript functionality in LESS to get the file name and do what you want; however, that is not the solution I offer here. Instead, this uses a two file solution.

Assuming a recent version of LESS (1.3.3), you have your `colorScheme.less` file and then another, let's call it `loader.less` file. There are just two lines in `loader.less`:

**loader.less**

```
@fileName: colorScheme;   
@import: "pathToFile/@{fileName}.less";
```

Now inside your `colorScheme.less` you have configured it to utilize the `@fileName` variable that you are setting in the `loader.less` file. So we have something like:

**colorScheme.less**

```
.@{fileName} p {color: red;}
.myClass-@{fileName} {color: blue;}
.@{fileName}-extended {color: yellow;}
```

compiling to...

```
.colorScheme p {color: red;}
.myClass-colorScheme {color: blue;}
.colorScheme-extended {color: yellow;}
```

Every place you have you have your `.colorScheme` you change that to `.@{fileName}`. Then, you can create new `loader` files to vary your class name (which is, I believe, partly what you want to do).